# How to dispaly long text in Vaadin 14

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow

How can I display long text using **Vaadin**? I tried it with **Label** and method `setText()`, but unfortunately it displays only first ~250 characters.

Answer (score 4):

The `Label` component in Vaadin 14 represents the HTML `<label>`, which according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) "represents a caption for an item in a user interface". As a caption component, it is not really suitable for long texts. It can be a little confusing if you are from the Vaadin 7/8 world where `Label` was a generic component for any text.

In Vaadin 14, I suggest using the `Paragraph` component. I represents the `<p>` tag in HTML.

This should work

```java
layout.add(new Paragraph("Hello from a very long text..."));
```